# How to show Tags inside Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wordpress-shortcode

I know how to display Wordpress Current Post Title. It's like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[auto_gallery search="' . get_the_title($post_id) . '"]'); ?>
```

I also know how to display Tag without the link. It's like this:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

My question is, how do I display the Current Tags inside my Shortcode?

Because the method below doesn't work.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[auto_gallery search="' . get_the_tags($post_id) . '"]'); ?>
```

Any idea?
Please also teach me how to display Current Category inside my Shortcode.

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way to display tags inside a Shortcode:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
echo do_shortcode('[auto_gallery search="' . $tag->name . '"]');
  }
}
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[auto_gallery search="' . implode(" ",get_the_tags($post_id)) . '"]'); ?>
```

get_the_tags() function return the array of tags and you need to pass the string in the shortcode so simply array to string conversion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).